# Boost Geometry: Union multiple polygons C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have an array of several Boost.Geometry polygons, and I need to union them into a single polygon. I have successfully implemented something that merges each successive polygon with the union of the previous two (just looping through them and unioning another polygon).

```cpp
multi_polygon polygons; // an array of initial polygons
multi_polygon border;   // the unioned polygons

for (polygon p : polygons) {
    // add another polygon each iteration
    multi_polygon tmp_poly;
    union_(border, p, tmp_poly);
    border = tmp_poly;
}
```

However, this takes quite a long time to execute. I heard mention in a video that the `assign` function could be used for this, but it was not detailed how, and I couldn't find anything else about this. How can I speed up this process?

Comment: Maybe implement a better algorithm to union all the polygons simultaneously with a line sweep. Failing that, try grouping them in a binary tree (merge 1 and 2, merge 3 and 4, merge results), this might be slightly faster.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure this is faster? This results in the same number of calls of union_()

Answer (score 3):

No, assign would only blindly add a polygon to a multi-polygon without merging them.

Currently in Boost.Geometry (1.73) there is no algorithm for merging multiple polygons into a valid multi-polygon.

You could however speed up your algorithm. It makes sense only to merge polygons that are intersecting. Everything else that is not intersecting could simply be added to the resulting multi-polygon. So you could:

- calculate bounding boxes of all polygons (`boost::geometry::envelope()`)
- put them (bounding box + id of a polygon) in the R-tree (`boost::geometry::index::rtree<>`)
- merge only those which bounding boxes intersect (`bgi::rtree<>::query()`), keeping the currently merged part (with `bg::union_()`), tracking ids of polygons merged with it (e.g. with some `bool` flags stored together with polygons in a container) and iteratively expanding the bounding box of a current part (`bg::expand()`)
- put all of the non-intersecting (non-mergeable) parts in a single multi-polygon

Answer (score 2):

This is not as efficient as the proposed answer, but I got some significant speedups from doing it this way without having to create a new algorithm from scratch.

```
multi_polygon polygons; // an array of initial polygons
multi_polygon border;   // the unioned polygons
multi_polygon tmp_poly; // a temporary variable

for (const polygon &p : polygons) {
    // add another polygon each iteration
    union_(border, p, tmp_poly);
    border = tmp_poly;
    boost::geometry::clear(tmp_poly);

}
```